# Protect Section in Word without limiting formatting in unprotected sections

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, microsoft-word-2003

Steps to create protected section (in Word 2003):

1. Insert -> Break...
2. Choose Section break, Continuous
3. Tools -> Protect Document...
4. Enable 'Allow only this type of editing in the document' in editing restrictions
5. In the drop down select 'Filling in forms'
6. Click on 'Select sections...' and uncheck the unprotected sections (eg. Section 2)
7. Click 'Yes, Start Enforcing Protection' and optionally set a password.

Now go to the unprotected section and in the Format menu options like 'Bullets and Numbering...' and 'Borders and Shading...' are greyed out.

How can you protect a section without limiting the features that can be used in the unprotected section?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adapted from Word's help:

1. On the Tools menu, click Protect Document.
2. In the Protect Document task pane, under Editing restrictions, select the Allow only this type of editing in the document check box, and then click No Changes or Comments
3. Select the parts of the document that you want to be unrestricted.
4. Select the Everyone check box in the Groups box.
5. Continue to select parts of the document and assign users permission to edit them, as you want.
6. Under Start enforcement, click Yes, Start Enforcing Protection.
7. Pick password protection or full authentication

I found this by pressing F1 and searching for "protect section"

Comment: Thank you. I spent ages googling this problem and didn't realise you could select a section to be excluded from No Changes restriction.